# html in facebook wall posts with graph api?

Tags: python, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

Does anyone know if I can create wall posts with html content using facebook's graph api? And if so, where I could find some documentation/examples? I don't see anything useful here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

It would appear that I can do this using fbml, but it also appears that they're trying to phase out fbml...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option for customizing wall posts are an embedded image or video.  You can't do HTML in the body so things like bold or italized texts are not possible.  What exactly were you trying to do that it wouldn't allow?

Comment: Sorry, definitely not possible.

Comment: bah, that's what I was afraid of. Thanks!

Comment: You can do custom html on iframe facebook fan pages, but not individual wall posts.

Answer (score 5):

They're not going to allow you to post HTML to a wall post for two main reasons:-

1. Malicious users can insert `<script>`s into the page DOM to do nasty things.
2. (rant) Facebook doesn't like formatting in their posts because it makes people look unique.

The first point is the most important; they won't allow HTML because it makes the site insecure, as it would on any other site. They might be nice enough to allow *certain* tags (like  and other formatting-only stuff), but it's very unlikely.

Comment: I *think* you still can with fbml, but I don't want to get started with something that's already being phased out...

Comment: That's why I didn't mention it :-) It's quite a shame that they don't even allow simple, harmless elements (such as `<b>` given above) as these don't hold any security concerns, unless you don't close them - then the page layout will mess up.

Comment: One of the reasons I stopped using MySpace was that user pages could be overly customized with black text on black background, loud images, autoplay music, flashing, and other 1994-ish HTML abuse. I think it's better that Facebook doesn't allow this. However, you could create an app that allows people to create and store rich text messages, and then post a link to a user's wall to refer them back to your app to read their rich content. This would be fairly easy to do. You could even generate an image of the text and display it in wall notices, approximating your stated goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify markdown formatting and use markdown in the message

```
message=# Hello world&formatting=MARKDOWN
```