# Posting HTML content on Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a rails app and using the Koala gem for the Facebook functionality.

I just want to know that

Can I post the HTML content on the Facebook wall of a user.

I am using this method for posting on the Facebook on behalf of user

@graph.put_object("me", "feed", :message => "I am writing on my wall!")

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [html in facebook wall posts with graph api?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394719/html-in-facebook-wall-posts-with-graph-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question is the same as yours, so the answers will be good for you too.

[html in facebook wall posts with graph api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394719/html-in-facebook-wall-posts-with-graph-api)